# How to find if each string in a variable has a regex

Tags: groovy

I'm struggling with implementing sanity check where we use a variable

```
def test = "/apps/damm/i18n /apps/dfdf/i18n /apps/fdf/i18n /apps/bsam/i18n /content"
```

So the issue is that I want to loop over this variable and for each of the string that contains as a regex " `^/apps/[^/]+/i18n/?.*`" - Meaning everything that has apps/something/i18n should be matched and if it starts with `/content`. If not then have to throw a exception.

How do you loop over a variable with multiple strings for each item seperated by space and check if those 2 regexes apply else throw exception?

I understand it maybe a very beginner question, but I couldn't get my head around it.

Comment: Can you edit the question to give examples of what should pass, and what should fail?  I'm struggling to understand the rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def test = "/apps/damm/i18n  /apps/dfdf/i18n /apps/fdf/i18n /apps/bsam/i18n /content"
assert ! test.split(/\s+/).find{ !(it ==~ '/apps/.*/i18n|/content.*') }
```